# Is it possible to ajax load a URL, then open the result in a new tab/window?

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova

Before you hate me because this goes against the purpose of ajax, here's my reasoning:

I have an HTML5 PhoneGap application that does data access to an asp.NET MVC web service using Form Authentication. I want to link to an action that returns a PDF file, then and show that file in mobile Safari. The problem is, if I do a `target="_blank"`, the request comes from safari, which doesn't have the forms authentication auth cookie, stored in the app, so the request is not authenticated. If I don't use `target="_blank"`, the request is authenticated properly, and loaded in the entire webview (PhoneGap) and I don't have access to the "Open in iBooks" or "Open in.." buttons provided by Safari.

I want to be able to ajax load the PDF, then display the result in safari, by opening in a new tab. Is this possible?

Edit: I'm trying this now:

```
$.ajax({
    url: downloadURL,
    type: 'GET',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //console.log(data);
        window.location = 'data:application/pdf;'+data;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error retrieving data: ' + errorThrown + '\n' + jqXHR);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    }
});
```

but this is resulting in an invalid pdf download. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: You could base64 encode the AJAX result, then load it with a data URI.

Comment: @arxanas could you expand on that? I'm not sure what data URI is.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=data+uri

Comment: @arxanas Sigh. Could have done without that sarcasm. I clearly searched, and spent time trying to figure it out. I edited my question to show my code addition from your suggestion, but haven't been able to figure it out.